# Find Best and Worst team per category-Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a scenario where I need to find best and worst team and their score per question category. Below is the input table.

[image]

The Output should be:

[image]

I tried the query but not able to find the team who is best and worst.

```
SELECT QUESTION_CATEGORY,TEAM_NAME ,MIN(MARKS) WORST_SCORE,MAX(MARKS) BEST_SCORE, 
FROM QUESTIONS GROUP BY  QUESTION_CATEGORY,TEAM_NAME
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with row_numbers in ascending and descending order and conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT QUESTION_CATEGORY
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_DESC=1 THEN TEAM_NAME END) AS BEST_TEAM
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_DESC=1 THEN MARKS END) AS BEST_MARKS
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_ASC=1 THEN TEAM_NAME END) AS WORST_TEAM
,MAX(CASE WHEN RN_ASC=1 THEN MARKS END) AS WORST_MARKS
FROM (SELECT QUESTION_CATEGORY,TEAM_NAME
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QUESTION_CATEGORY ORDER BY MARKS) as RN_ASC
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY QUESTION_CATEGORY ORDER BY MARKS DESC) as RN_DESC
      FROM QUESTIONS
     ) T
GROUP BY QUESTION_CATEGORY
```

If there can be ties in highest/lowest marks add a tie-breaking condition in `ORDER BY` of `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one to get desired result without using sub-query:

```
SELECT 
    QUESTION_CATEGORY,
    MIN(TEAM_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY MARKS) AS BEST_TEAM, 
    MIN(TEAM_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY MARKS) AS WORST_TEAM, 
    MIN(MARKS) WORST_SCORE,
    MAX(MARKS) BEST_SCORE, 
FROM QUESTIONS 
GROUP BY QUESTION_CATEGORY;
```

See [FIRST](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) documentation

Comment: i keep forgetting this `KEEP`.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but I would try this path:

```
select question_category, team_name, marks
from questions
where marks in (select max(marks) 
                from questions q1 
                where q1.question_category = questions.question_category)
or marks in (select min(marks) 
             from questions q1 
             where q1.question_category = questions.question_category)
```